# How to reuse mocked Cypress tests to run against real APIs?

Tags: cypress

I have Cypress tests that run with local mocks/fixtures using [`cy.intercept`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept).

I'd like to reuse these tests to run against a production URL and disable the network interception so that the tests run against real APIs.

Is these a way to disable all `cy.intercept`s, or am I thinking in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Intercepted Requests section](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Intercepted-requests) will help you achieve this, but you might have to rewrite your `cy.intercept()` calls.

As stated, you need to use the routeHandler to apply a condition to stub or not you api calls.

```js
cy.intercept('GET', '/yourEndpoint', (req) => {
    if (Cypress.config('baseUrl') === 'prodUrl') {
        req.continue();
    } else {
        req.reply(your stub here);
    }
});
```

---

### Edit: Example of cy.intercept() overwrite

I suppose you are using one of these `cy.intercept()` signatures:
[image]

In that case, you would need to use the `Cypress.Commands.overwrite()` to transform your `staticResponse` variable into a `routeHandler` callback to end up with one of these:
[image]

Here's an example with the second signature `(method, url, staticResponse)`:

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('intercept', (originalFn, method, url, staticResponse) => {
    originalFn(method, url, (req) => {
        if (Cypress.config('baseUrl') === 'prodUrl') {
           req.continue();
        } else {
           req.reply(staticResponse);
        }
    });
});
```

If you use multiple signatures, you would need a logic to accept 2 or 3 parameters and map them accordingly to `originalFn()`.

Comment: Feels cumbersome to do this for every single intercept, but maybe overriding the `cy.intercept()` command to do this automatically is a good idea 

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin "cypress-skip-test". It's possible to skip tests or code blocks depending on OS, browser or environment variables. Assuming that you set your interceptors in before or beforeEach you can put a "onlyOn" or "skipOn" around the interceptor call. Depending on a environment "production" you skip the setting of the interceptors.

You call:

```
CYPRESS_ENVIRONMENT=production npx cypress run
```

and you skip:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  skipOn('production', () => {
    cy.intercept(...);
  })
});
```

- For more information about the plugin see: [cypress-skip-test](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-skip-test)
- And especially about setting environment see: [ENVIRONMENT](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-skip-test#environment)

Comment: This won't quite work for me because I have `cy.intercept()`s in the tests themselves because sometimes I need to provide multiple different responses to a single request URL in a single test.

Comment: You can do this also in the tests themselves, but it's a lot of work if you have many of these intercepts.